# CSS Html: Text not truncating enough causing container to grow

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have a `angular-material card` inside here is a `mat-table`, containing notes.

HTML And CSS Below

```
<div fxLayout="column" style="flex: 1;">
        <mat-card class="card-info" style="margin-right: 10px; max-height: 167px;">
            <mat-card-content>

                <div class="example-container">

                    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="notes">

                        <!-- Name Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.created | date }} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Weight Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="subject">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Subject </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.subject}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Symbol Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="note">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Note </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                    </mat-table>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>

        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.example-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 500px;
    min-width: 300px;
  }

  .mat-table {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
  }

  mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Although the text inside the cell does truncate, it doesn't truncate enough and causes the card to grow. I don't want to put a max-width, as I want it to flex to fill remainder of the screen.

Here is an image of how it looks:

[image]

As you can see it makes the card grow off the screen.

Comment: Give `word-wrap: break-word` a shot.

Comment: That style is already on mat-cell.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't see it in the question.